# Passing an array to Html.ActionLink()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I followed this example:

[ASP.NET MVC - Pass array object as a route value within Html.ActionLink(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717690/asp-net-mvc-pass-array-object-as-a-route-value-within-html-actionlink/717732#717732)

But, my Action is always called with `null`. What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (OrderDetail od in order.OrderDetails)
{
   rvd.Add("key" + count++, productID);
   rvd.Add("key" + count++, productName);
}

@Html.ActionLink(linkText, "Renew", "Orders", rvd, new Dictionary<string, object>())
```

The query string is correctly generated, like `?key0=dog&key1=cat&key2=fish...`, but I get a null parameter in my Action below:

```
public ActionResult Renew(RouteValueDictionary rvd)
{
   // 'rvd' is null here!
}
```

Please note: I don't know the number of parameters in advance.

Comment: more code, what is rvd and count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine what is happening is you are expecting the model binder to bind your array to a RouteValueDictionary, but the model binder doesn't know that key0=dog&key1=cat&key2=fish is supposed to be a dictionary. I would recommend changing your code to accept a string array. To do this, your query string needs to look something like this: `?rvd=dog&rvd=cat&rvd=fish`

And your Action...

```
public ActionResult Renew(string[] rvd)
{
   // 'rvd' is no longer null here!
}
```

The important part is `rvd` is the parameter name in your action, as well as the name of each element in the querystring: ?`rvd`=dog&`rvd`=cat&`rvd`=fish. If you really want to use a dictionary instead of a string array, then your querystring should look like this: <strike>`?rvd[0]=dog&rvd[1]=cat&rvd[2]=fish`, giving each item an array index, but you would probably have to change your parameter from RouteValueDictionary to `Dictionary<string,string>`, I'm not quite sure</strike>. [More info here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx). **EDIT**: See Darin's comment about binding to a dictionary, as I believe his is correct.

You may have to write your own extension for Html.ActionLink that accepts an array (or whatever `OrderDetails` is) and creates the querystring as an array. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752721/asp-net-mvc-routedata-and-arrays) looks like a pretty good starting place.

Answer (score 4):

> The query string is correctly generated, like ?key0=dog&key1=cat&key2=fish...

No, this is not a correct url. A correct url would have looked like this:

```
?%5B0%5D.Key=123&%5B0%5D.Value=dog&%5B1%5D.Key=456&%5B1%5D.Value=cat...
```

which would have mapped to:

```
public ActionResult Renew(Dictionary<int, string> rvd)
{
    ...
}
```

You could write a custom ActionLink to generate this url:

```
public static class LinkExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyActionLink(
        this HtmlHelper html,
        string linkText,
        string actionName,
        string controllerName,
        IDictionary<string, string> parameters
    )
    {
        var a = new TagBuilder("a");
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var query = string.Join("&", parameters.Select((x, i) => string.Format("[{0}].Key={1}&[{0}].Value={2}", i, urlHelper.Encode(x.Key), urlHelper.Encode(x.Value))));
        var url = string.Format(
            "{0}?{1}",
            urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, null, html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme),
            query
        );
        a.Attributes["href"] = url;
        a.SetInnerText(linkText);
        return new HtmlString(a.ToString());
    }
}
```

which you could use like this in your view:

```
@Html.MyActionLink(
    linkText, 
    "Renew", 
    "Orders", 
    order.OrderDetails.ToDictionary(x => x.ProductID.ToString(), x => x.ProductName)
)
```

You can read more about the correct wire format for binding to various collections in [`this blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx).

Comment: I added square brackets and the URL now is: `http://localhost:55058/Orders/Renew?key%5B0%5D=dog&key%5B1%5D=cat&key%5B2%5D=fish` and even changing the Action signature to `public ActionResult Renew(Dictionary<int, string> rvd)` I still get null. Do you know why?