# Print model data without saving

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
 if (saleDetails.length) {        
        var htmlData;
        var paymentStatus = 0;
        if ($('#PaymentStatus option:selected').val() != 0) {
            paymentStatus = $('#PaymentStatus option:selected').text()
        }
        var SaleAmount = parseFloat(total + vat).toFixed(2);
        var data = {
            'AccountID': $('#hdnAccountID').val(),
            'QuoteID': $('#hdnQuoteID').val(),
            'BranchID': $('#BranchID option:selected').val(),
            'PONO': $('#PONO').val(),
            'PaymentStatus': $('#PaymentStatus').val(),
            'SalesDate': $('#SaleDate').val(),
            'PaymentStatus': paymentStatus,
            'PaymentTypeID': $('#PaymentType option:selected').val(),
            'VAT': vat,
            'TotalAmount': invoiceAmount,
            'DiscountAmount': $('#discInput').val(),
            'AmountPaid': $('#amountPaid').val(),
            'SaleDetails': saleDetails
        };
        var json = JSON.stringify({ 'model': data });

public ActionResult printOrder(Models.DTO.Sales model)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
            //return View(model);            
        }
```

I am working on POS , In sales client requirement is that we should give him an option of print   , so that if client click on Print button we should open a new tab and show invoice , so client can take out print and if customer pay him then client will save SalesOrder. 
The problem I am facing is that I am unable to open new tab from controller . And if I am trying to do this from java script I am unable to pass model to view from java script. 
So please help me in this issue as I am not too much expert in MVC.

Comment: You can simply create an action to render the data on view and allow user to print the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Html.ActionLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) to open the page in new tab from your Razor page as below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print", "Action", new { controller="PrintOrder" }, new { target="_blank" })
```

`Html.ActionLink` however does not allow you to pass complex objects. You can use trick as mentioned in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197811/asp-net-mvc-trouble-passing-model-in-html-actionlink-routevalues#14597115) answer to pass your model. From the post:

> MODEL: Make static Serialize and Deserialize methods in the class like
>
> ```
> public class XYZ { 
>   // Some Fields
>   public string X { get; set; }
>   public string Y { get; set; }
>   public string X { get; set; }
>
>   // This will convert the passed XYZ object to JSON string
>   public static string Serialize(XYZ xyz)
>   {
>       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>       return serializer.Serialize(xyz);
>   }
>
>   // This will convert the passed JSON string back to XYZ object
>   public static XYZ Deserialize(string data)
>   {
>       var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
>       return serializer.Deserialize<XYZ>(data);
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> VIEW: Now convert your complex object to JSON string before passing it in
>
> ```
> Action View <%= Html.ActionLink(Model.x, "SomeAction", new { modelString = XYZ.Serialize(Model) })%>
> ```
>
> CONTROLLER: Get the
>   object as string in Action method and convert it back to object before
>
> ```
>  using public ActionResult SomeAction(string modelString) { XYX xyz = XYX.Deserialize(modelString); }
> ```