# Adding an IEnumerable to a RouteValueDictionary - is this possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 2, and I've got a slight problem. I need to produce an url from a list of values.

Using the following code:

```
RouteValueDictionary dic = new RouteValueDictionary();
dic.Add("mylist", new [] { 1, 2, 3 });
return helper.Action(dic["action"] as string, dic["controller"] as string, dic);
```

I get the url `/whatever/System.Int32[]` which obviously is not what I am after.

What is the ASP.Net MVC 2 preferred way of generating such an URL? I know the modelbinder can handle lists, but how to generate it?

A quick note on how it is done in MVC 3 would also be appreciated (if the method differs).

Comment: How are you expecting your URL to look with this list?

Comment: /whatever?list[0]=1&list[1]=2 would work with the default modelbinder, but prettier for this scenario would probably be list=1&list=2&list=3. In any case, anything that works with both the default model binder and the default URL generator

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Pass array object as a route value within Html.ActionLink(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717690/asp-net-mvc-pass-array-object-as-a-route-value-within-html-actionlink)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this prior response helps you (mvc 3 would be the same - its the same routing engine as part of asp.net 4)

[ASP.NET MVC - Pass array object as a route value within Html.ActionLink(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717690/asp-net-mvc-pass-array-object-as-a-route-value-within-html-actionlink)

Comment: Ah thanks. Didn't manage to find that one through either SO or google - weird.

Comment: My brain is plugged directly in to google via the ICaffeine interface haha

Answer (score 0):

You could always make your own List class with a `ToString()` override that prints how you would like it. That seems like the simplest (but perhaps the most 'hackish') way to do this.

```
public MyRouteList<T> : List<T>
{
     public override string ToString()
     {
          return string.Join("&", this.Select(x => "list=" + x.ToString()));
     }
}
```