# How to pass a list in a get request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, encoding, model-binding

I have an url that works for passing a List of strings

```
/Home/Index?Person%5B0%5D=Myname&Person%5B1%5D=Yourname
```

Unencoded it is

```
/Home/Index?Person[0]=Myname&Person[1]=Yourname
```

The Action Method is

```
public ActionResult(List<string> person)
 {
...
}
```

The Parameter List person will be correctly filled with the values Myname and Yourname.

I need to redirect to this url using RedirectToAction

I would usually do

```
RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new {Parameter1=value1})
```

But obviously I cant use Person%5B0%5D as a parameter name, because it has ivalid characters.

How can I create such a link or should I use a different URL - scheme?

Comment: Did you try decoded version `Person[0]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Pass array object as a route value within Html.ActionLink(...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717690/asp-net-mvc-pass-array-object-as-a-route-value-within-html-actionlink)

Comment: @George Person[0] is also not a valid property name. The url works, but I cant create the link.

Comment: @CodeCaster This is a different question. The link has an array with a different url scheme. I might find some usefull information there, but I dont see an answer to my problem.

Comment: The answer is in there, it's "use a RouteValueDictionary".

Comment: If its just strings you can always use `/Home/Index?Person=Myname&Person=Yourname` with the parameter being `string[] person`

Comment: @stephen I shure can, but the real url is more complex and I need the roules in the routing table to reflect the real urls.

Comment: @CodeCaster Using RouteValueDictionary works. Do you want to add it as an answer? Its hard to see on the other question.

Comment: @Malcolm feel free to self-answer with your solution. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster  Thnx, I just wait for some time

Comment: What if you call it like RedirectToAction("Index","Home",new {person=new List<string>(){"person1", "person2"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i worked on your query and finally got the result just check this code find weather it work with your query.

**Controller code :**

```
public ActionResult showString()
        {
            try
            {

                IEnumerable<string> persons = new[] { "myname", "urname" };
                var values = new RouteValueDictionary(
                persons
                    .Select((sampleper, index) => new {sampleper, index })
                    .ToDictionary(
                        key => string.Format("[{0}]", key.index),
                        value => (object)value.sampleper
                    )
            );
            return RedirectToAction("details", values);




            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

**and another action method is details with list as parameter**

```
public ActionResult details(IEnumerable<string> persons)
        {
             ViewBag.person = persons;



            return View();
        }
```

it also works if you pass the link as

```
http://localhost:2266/Home/details?%5B0%5D=myname&%5B1%5D=urname
```

the view of details action method is

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "details";
}

<h2>details</h2>
<ul>
  @foreach (var i in ViewBag.person)
  { 

  <li>@i</li>


  }

</ul>
```